# Is there a proper term for a "continuum-convex" set?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, terminology

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and for any compactly supported Borel probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $X$, define the mean $\mu_\mathbb{P}$ by $\mu_\mathbb{P}=\int_X x \, \mathbb{P}(dx)$.

I want to say that a Borel set $S \subset X$ is *continuum-convex* if every compactly supported Borel probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $X$ with $\mathbb{P}(S)=1$ has $\mu_\mathbb{P} \in S$.

> Is there a recognised term for what I have called "continuum-convex"?

The point behind this definition:

The standard "set-theoretic" definition of a "convex subset of a vector space" is a subset that is closed under finite convex combinations, i.e. under weighted averages where the weighting is discrete. I want a stronger notion where the weighting is allowed to be completely general, i.e. not necessarily discrete (hence the term "continuum").

---

Note that

- if $S$ is continuum-convex then $S$ is convex;
- if $S$ is closed and convex then $S$ is continuum-convex.

However, neither of these implications is reversible. For example:

Suppose that $X$ is the completion of the vector space $\mathcal{M}(M)$ of finite signed measures on a compact metric space $M$ where $\mathcal{M}(M)$ is equipped with a norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{M}(M)}$ whose topology is the topology of weak convergence. (E.g. one can find a sequence of continuous functions $g_n \colon M \to [0,2^{-n}]$ such that $\|\mu\|_{\mathcal{M}(M)}:=\sum_n |\int_M g_n \, d\mu|$ is such a norm.) Then,

- the set of all finitely supported probability measures on $M$ is convex, but not continuum-convex;
- given a non-closed Borel set $A \subset M$ and a non-empty interval $I \subset (0,1]$, the set of all probability measures assigning to $A$ a value in $I$ is not closed in $X$, but nonetheless is continuum-convex.

---

**Update.** The question has essentially been answered by Gerald Edgar in a comment: there is a term "measure convex" whose exact definition varies between authors, but the idea behind it is exactly what I've presented above.

I realise that I should also have mentioned: every convex Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is measure convex, so my question is really about the problem of infinite dimensions.

Comment: Apologies if this is a stupid question, but what does “$\int$” mean in this context? Bochner integral? Pettis integral? Something else?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen No, thanks for the question. I was picturing the Bochner integral, but was assuming (maybe wrongly) that any other well-defined integral with respect to a compactly supported probability measure would give the same answer. That's why I didn't specify.

Comment: $\mu_{\mathbb{P}}$ is the barycentre of $\mu$. So perhaps there is an established term in the literature on barycentres ("barycentre-closed"?).

Comment: A related property is $\sigma$-convex (if $\sum a_i = 1$, $a_i > 0$, then the infinite convex combination $\sum a_i \mu_i$ belongs); if the space of measures is weakly metrizable, then this notion is possibly equivalent to what you want. Or perhaps just convex and weakly closed?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/368918/454  and  https://mathoverflow.net/q/152907/454    and maybe   https://mathoverflow.net/q/63922/454

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Okay, thanks! Even though it seems different sources give different definitions of "measure convex", I think that that's the term to go for!