# Does an uncountable convex combination of elements of a set lie in the convex hull of the set in finite dimension?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, convex-analysis

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and that $C\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ is a convex subset of $\mathcal{F}$.

Is it true that an uncountable convex-combination of elements of $C$, $\int f(x)C(x)dx$ is in $C$,

where $\int f(x)dx=1$, $f(x)\geq0$ and $C(x)\in C$? What are the conditions for this to happen?

What if $\mathcal{F}$ is infinite-dimensional? (Here I suppose that the answer is no)

To be more precise, I'm interested in the case where $\mathcal{F}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space of functions $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $C$ is a convex subset. If $X$ is a random variable on $C$, is it true that the function $\mathbb{E}_X[g_X]$ (defined as the function $x\mapsto\mathbb{E}_X[g_X(x)]$ ) is in $C$ if the functions $g_X$ are in $C$?

I'm asking this question because I could only see this problem treated for $\mathbb{R}^n$. My understanding is that for $\mathbb{R}^n$ this is true.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811880/generalized-convex-hull-is-just-ordinary-convex-hull/2812508#2812508 , https://mathoverflow.net/q/63922/454 , https://mathoverflow.net/q/368918/454 .

Comment: Try looking at the open unit interval in the real line.  You obviously need a closure property.  This is a well studied concept (that of barycentre of a measure).  The barycentre of a probability meadure on a closed convex subset $C$ of a locally convex space lies in $C$, a trivial consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: In fact you do not need a closure property: an *open* convex subset $U$ of a Banach space $E$ works as well: if $f:X\to E$ is Bochner integrable on some probability space $(X,\mathcal S, m)$, with $f(X)\subset U,$ then $\int_Xfdm\in U$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\F{\mathcal F}\newcommand\si{\sigma}\newcommand\Si{\Sigma}$

1. You should have defined the meaning of the integrals $\int f(x)\,dx$ and $\int f(x)C(x)\,dx$. These should be properly understood as integrals with respect to a probability measure, say $\mu$, defined on a $\si$-algebra over $\F$ such that $C\in\F$ and $\mu(C)=1$. Also, it is then not a good idea to denote elements of $C$ by $C(x)$.
   So, the question can then be properly restated as follows:

> Suppose that $\Si$ and $\mu$ are as above. Is it then always true that $\int c\,\mu(dc)\in C$?

2. In the case when $\F=\R^d$ we have the easy "yes" answer (and you said you know how to treat this case); here we need to assume the natural condition that all affine subspaces of $\F$ are in $\Si$; in particular, it would be enough for $\Si$ to contain the Borel $\si$-algebra over $\R^d$. The case of any finite-dimensional $\F$ then immediately follows, because then $\F$ is linearly isomorphic to $\R^d$ for some $d$.
3. For infinite-dimensional $\F$, the answer is "no" in general. E.g., let $\F=C_0[0,\infty)$, the topological vector space of all continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ vanishing at $\infty$, with the topology defined by the $\sup$ norm. Let $\Si$ be the Borel $\si$-algebra over $\F$. Let $C$ be the convex hull (or the span) of the set $C_*:=\{c_x\colon x\in(0,\infty)\}$, where $c_x$ is the (decreasing exponential) function in $\F$ defined by the formula $c_x(t):=e^{-xt}$ for $t\in[0,\infty)$. Let $\mu$ be the probability measure on $\Si$ defined by the formula
   $$\mu(B):=\int_{(0,\infty)}dx\,e^{-x}\,1(c_x\in B)$$
   for all $B\in\Si$. Then $\mu(C)=\mu(C_*)=1$.
   Let
   $$b:=\int c\,\mu(dc),$$
   so that
   $$b(t)=\int_{(0,\infty)}dx\,e^{-x}\,e^{-tx}=\frac1{t+1}$$
   for all $t\in[0,\infty)$. Then $b\notin C$ -- because, in contrast with $b$, all functions in $C$ decrease to $0$ exponentially fast near $\infty$.

---

Here is another, possibly simpler, "infinite-dimensional" counterexample. Let $\F=\R^\R$, the set of all real-valued functions on $\R$. Let $\Si$ be the powerset of $\F$. Let $C$ be the set of all polynomial functions in $\F$. Let the probability measure on $\Si$ be defined by the condition
$$\mu(\{p_n\})=\frac1{en!}$$
for $n=0,1,\dots$, where $p_n(t):=t^n$ for $t\in\R$. Then for
$$g:=\int c\,\mu(dc)$$
and $t\in\R$ we have
$$g(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(t)\mu(\{p_n\})=e^{t-1}.$$
So, $g\notin C$, because $g'=g\ne0$, whereas $c'\ne c$ for any nonzero $c\in C$.

The latter counterexample shows that even a countable convex combination of points of a convex subset $C$ of an infinite-dimensional linear space does not have to be in $C$.

Comment: The question says that it wants to consider also infinite dimensional vector spaces.  But, even in the finite-dimensional case, how does one handle an *arbitrary* measure?  (The problem isn't clear, at least not to me, what measure it considers on Euclidean space.)

Comment: @LSpice in a finite-dimensional case this holds for any probabilistic measure $\mu$ on our convex set  $C$. Indeed, if the barycentre of $\mu$ does not belong to $C$, it may be (not strongly) separated from $C$ by a hyperplane $\alpha$. Then $\mu$ is concentrated on $\alpha\cap C$ and we may induct by dimension.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Thank you for this nice explanation of the finite-dimensional case -- so that now I don't have to explain it. :-)

Comment: @LSpice : The finite-dimensional case has just been nicely explained by Fedor Petrov. Also, I have added a counterexample for the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @LSpice : Also, another "infinite-dimensional" counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer! How would it change if instead of a vector space, now the C is a convex subset of an n-dimensional manifold, not necessarily a vector space? Does it deserve to be a question of its own? Thanks!

Comment: Of course if $F$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space, you need $C$ to be closed, otherwise an example is $C$= any linear subspace of $F$ with countable Hamel dimension.  There are  always infinite convex combinations of  $C$ of the form   $\sum_{k\ge0}\epsilon_k  c_k\in F\setminus C$.

Comment: I have posted a companion question to this question where we are not in a vector space anymore but on a manifold. Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460372/does-this-expectation-over-this-convex-set-belong-to-the-set if interested

Comment: @rick : What do you mean by "manifold" in "convex subset of an n-dimensional manifold"? If you mean here ["topological manifold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Mathematical_definition) or something like that, then how would you define "convex subset" and the integral with respect to a measure? If by "n-dimensional manifold" you mean just an $n$-dimensional affine space, then this space is affinely isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, so that the desired result follows immediately from that for $\mathbb R^n$.